# HttpURLConnection client and API different Header from same client

Tags: java, session, servlets, httpurlconnection

In terms of security I try to extend the communication between my client and my API with a session. The client sends its header to the API and the API generates a session.

Client:

```
public static JSONObject send(String info)
{ 
  StringBuffer resp = new StringBuffer();

  try
  {
    URL url = new URL( "http://localhost:8080/myapi/" );
    HttpURLConnection con = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection() );

    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty( "USER-AGENT", USER_AGENT );
    con.setRequestProperty( "Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
    con.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json" );
    con.setDoOutput( true );

    String data = info ;

    DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream( con.getOutputStream);

    output.writeBytes( data );
    output.flush();
    output.close();


    int returnCode = con.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    if (returnCode==200)
    {
      reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    }
    else
    {
      reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getErrorStream()));
    }

    String input;
    while( ( input = reader.readLine() ) != null )
    {
      resp.append( input );
    }
    reader.close();

    return new JSONObject( resp.toString() );
  }
  catch( Exception e )
  {
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

    return new JSONObject( resp.toString() );
  }
  finally
  {
    if( con != null )
    {
      con.disconnect();
    }  
  }
}
```

API:

```
HttpServletRequest request = requestGlobals.getHttpServletRequest();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Idea: The first request with `send` creates the connection with the API and the API generates the session which is stored inside it. The second `send` from the same client should send the same header, so the API can generate the same session and compared it to the saved one. For example, I am able to guarantee further calls only after a successful login

Problem: If the connection is reestablished on the second `send`, the same client sends a different header with a different content length, resulting in a different session being generated. I tried to set a `if( con == null )` around the area where the connection is build at the client but that didn't solve my problem.

Question: What do i have to do so that the second `send` uses the already existing connection or send the same header?